# Why can't I get destroy() call for skrollr to work?

Tags: javascript, html, skrollr

Hello I am trying to use skrollr on a responsive site, and I just want to turn it off for mobile and then back on for table / desktop. I keep getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'destroy'. A point in the right direction would be helpful as I wasn't able to find an example that is using the destroy call for skrollr.

Below is the code that I am using:

```
var s = skrollr.init(
{
    forceHeight: false,
    constants: 
    {
        box: '50p'
    }
});

// set breakpoints
$(window).setBreakpoints(
{
    // use only largest available vs use all available
    distinct: true, 
    // array of widths in pixels where breakpoints
    breakpoints: 
    [
        480,
        768  
    ] 
}); 

$(window).bind('enterBreakpoint480',function() 
{
    console.log("this is now 480");
    s.destroy();
});

$(window).bind('enterBreakpoint768',function() 
{
    console.log("this is now 768");
    s = skrollr.get();
});
```

Comment: can you log and check what 's' before destory() is called on it?

Comment: I get back this:Object {get: function, init: function, VERSION: "0.6.22", setStyle: function, addEvent: function…}
VERSION: "0.6.22"
addEvent: function (element, names, callback) {
get: function () {
init: function (options) {
removeEvent: function (element, names, callback) {
setStyle: function (el, prop, val) {
__proto__: Object

Comment: ok so I figured out that if I init skrollr at the top, var s = skrollr.init(); then I can call the destroy method on it, but it doesn't seem to remove skrollr from my site when in mobile sizes?

Comment: `if(s) s.destroy();`, because `skrollr.get()` will return `undefined`, if not initialized.